# Are there teachings of Rabbenu Moshe HaDarshan found outside of Rashi?

Tags: jewish-books, rashi, rishonim

Are there any teachings of [Rabbenu Moshe HaDarshan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ha-Darshan) found either as a collected work, or cited by authorities other than Rashi?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ha-Darshan#As_Haggadist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a sefer called Bereishis Rabbasi](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?667&) which was written either by Rav Moshe HaDarshan or one of his students. He is also quoted in many places in Pirush HaRokeach Al HaTorah and Tosafos HaShalem Al HaTorah (things which are not quoted by Rashi).